Stored procedure automatically triggered from ADF can't update or insert tables
I have a SP as below. When this is trigged from ADF using scheduled trigger it is not inserting the  data as per the conditions. However, when this is triggered manually from ADF it is working as expected.Any idea what could be wrong here?
CREATE PROC [schema1].[sp1] AS
BEGIN
 

DECLARE @date_today                 DATE

 
select @date_today = getdate()
print @date_today
 

Truncate table T1

 
 
IF NOT EXISTS
(select month from T3
where condition1 <= @date_today and condition2 >=@date_today)
    BEGIN
     INSERT INTO T1
     VALUES ('0')
    END
 
    ELSE
    BEGIN
     INSERT INTO T1
     VALUES ('1')
    END
 
 
 
END

-Tried executing this SP manually from SSMS and it works as expected
-Tried executing  manually from ADF activity and it works

Do you get an error message when the pipeline is triggered? Do other stored procedures work on triggered pipelines?

Is the trigger published?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
